# Are there any public subversion hosts that will let my use my own repository?

Tags: svn, hosting

Basically, I have a project I've been working on for a while, and would like to push to the public as an open source project of one sort or another (to be determined, but out of scope of this question anyway).

The question is, I've been using my own subversion repository locally to manage my code. Are there any hosts out there that will let me push my own repository onto their server so that all my revision history is not lost when I go public, or am I stuck with pushing my first public version to one host or another and moving forward from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google code [will let you do that](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_an_existing_Subversion_repository?).

Answer (score 0):

Sourceforge [too](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SVN%20adminrepo).

Answer (score 0):

[Tigris](http://www.tigris.org/) too.